# Search full string or substrings in two columns

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, ormlite

I have 2 columns (product name and description) and try create search. For example:

Table "products":

```
id   name             description
---------------------------------
1    Inspiron 7720    Intel i7
2    Inspiron 7720    Intel i5
3    Inspiron 5720    Intel i7
4    Asus Zenbook     Intel i5
```

and in search bar - "Inspiron 5720 i7".

How can I get result:
1) id=3 Inspiron 5720 (full coincidence)
2) id=1 Inspiron 7720 (partial coincidence)
3) id=2 Inspiron 7720 (partial coincidence)

I may use something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM product WHERE LOWER( product.product_name ) LIKE  '%"
                + searchString + "%'" +
                " OR LOWER( product.product_description ) LIKE  '%"
                + searchString + "%'"
```

But I belive, that is most clear solution.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation, use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I think this wont return the rows for the description since you searh query would look like select * from product where description like '%Inspiron 5720 i7%', this wont return any results for description because Inspiron 5720 does not exist in the description column.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using prepared statements you could check out if [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) fits your needs:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM product 
  WHERE FREETEXT(product.product_name + ' ' + product.product_description, ? )");

pstmt.setString(1, searchString);
```

==EDIT==

Try to order the results by similarity by using `ORDER BY` in combination with `SOUNDEX`

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM product 
  WHERE FREETEXT(product.product_name + ' ' + product.product_description, ? )
  ORDER BY 
    ABS(SOUNDEX(product.product_name + ' ' + product.product_description)
      -SOUNDEX(?)) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a query with the single words given, count the matches and compare with the number of words.

```
select
  id,
  name,
  case 
    when score = 3 then 'full coincidence'
    else 'partial coincidence'
  end as match
from
(
  select id,
    case when name like '%Inspiron%' or description like '%Inspiron%' then 1 else 0 end +
    case when name like '%5720%' or description like '%5720%' then 1 else 0 end +
    case when name like '%i7%' or description like '%i7%' then 1 else 0 end as score
  from mytable
)
where score > 0
order by score desc;
```

EDIT: To get better results you would use LOWER as you suggested yourself and add blanks to find whole words.

```
name like '%Inspiron%'
```

becomes

```
lower(' ' + name + ' ') like '% inspiron %'
```